# XCTest async code doesn't get executed in 'tearDown() async throws' method

Tags: swift, testing, xctest, swift-concurrency

From Apple's XCTest [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/set_up_and_tear_down_state_in_your_tests) regarding `setUp` and `tearDown` it said to perform async code in `tearDown() async throws` method.

And in my case, I create some test data in server with API call, and I'd like to clean it after the test case execution is completed. The ideal place is `tearDown` from my understanding.

```
override func tearDown() async throws {
    // This is the tearDown() async instance method.
    // XCTest calls it after each test method.
    // Perform any asynchronous per-test cleanup here.
}
```

Then I have a small test, the result is this `tearDown() async throws` method is called after test case execution, but print code in DispatchQueue `print("~ make an API call")` is never executed, and the test is completed soon. Although I think this method is designed to handle async scenario from what Apple doc said, for instance cleaning server data with API call.

```
    override func tearDown() async throws {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            print("~ make an API call")
        }
    }
    
    // tearDown test method
    func testDemo() {
        print("~ Test started")
    }
```

Thus, my question is what is the property way to clean test data asynchronously in tearDown method?

Comment: Well, nice try. But I do check in our server the test data is not deleted after the test is completed. And also I made breakpoint in the DispatchQueue closure, the code inside is never got executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing an old-style `DispatchQueue`-based async method with the new, language feature, `async` method.

From the type systems perspective, `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` is a sync method, since it isn't marked as `async`, hence when you call it from an `async` method, the `async` method will treat is as a synchronous method and continue execution right after that method returns, rather than waiting for its completion to be executed asynchronously.

You can resolve this issue several ways. You can either wrap the completion-based `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter` method in a `Continuation` and hence turn it into an actual `async` method or you can simply use `Task.sleep`.

```
override func tearDown() async throws {
  try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
  // make the API call here
}
```

Comment: You are correct, `async` and `await` is the new format to write async code. Let me have a retry.